# Why is my systemd-networkd not aquiring an IP address via DHCP?

Tags: dhcp, systemd, gentoo, systemd-networkd

On my notebook running Gentoo, I set up the following things:

- Kernel with all necessary settings and modules
- WPA_Supplicant
- Systemd
- Systemd-Networkd

Almost everything works as expected, the connection to my WiFi is established and stable. The only problem is, that I can't get systemd-networkd to act as a DHCP client to receive a valid IPv4 address.

This is my `/etc/systemd/network/50-dhcp.network`:

```
[Match]
Name=*

[Network]
DHCP=yes
```

As I understood, this will trigger a DHCP call for every network interface. Also, there should not be any additional DHCP client software necessary (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1047654) for example).

So, if I don't install any additional software, just nothing will happen after being connected to the WiFi. `ifconfig` shows:

```
wlp59s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 280  bytes 21542 (21.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 232  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 8  bytes 2304 (2.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

There's also nothing useful in the journal, but this line:

```
... wlp59s0: Configuring with /etc/systemd/network/50-dhcp.network
```

Next thing I tried was installing DHClient. It won't work automatically, but if I issue just `dhclient`, it works and I get an IP address within the desired range. The journal says:

```
... dhclient[407]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.0.35 on wlp59s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
... dhclient[407]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp58s0u1u2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
... dhclient[407]: DHCPACK of 192.168.0.35 from 192.168.0.1
... dhclient[407]: bound to 192.168.0.35 -- renewal in 348891 seconds.
... dhclient[407]: Can't create /var/run/dhcp/dhcpclient.pid: No such file or directory
... dhclient[407]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp58s0u1u2 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
```

I'd like to have this happen automatically once connecting to my WiFi. Can you please show me where my mistake is? I've been searching quite a while, but I didn't find any clue.

One more note: If I install dhcpcd (instead of/alongside dhclient), in fact I *am* getting an IP address automatically, but that one seems to be created quite randomly and doesn't belong to my net. Journal says:

```
... systemd-networkd[234]: wlp59s0: Configuring with /etc/systemd/network/50-dhcp.network
...
... dhcpcd[343]: wlp59s0: connected to Access Point: my.wlan.ssid
... dhcpcd[343]: wlp59s0: IAID d0:fe:1b:39
... dhcpcd[343]: wlp59s0: soliciting a DHCP lease
... dhcpcd[343]: wlp59s0: probing for an IPv4LL address
... dhcpcd[343]: wlp59s0: using IPv4LL address 169.254.211.13
... dhcpcd[343]: wlp59s0: adding route to 169.254.0.0/16
```

(But, as stated before, I thought I just wouldn't need any additional DHCP client? Anyway, the result with DHCPCD is not the desired one.)

Comment: I'm quite embarrassed, but all of a sudden it started working...  I had tried multiple times before with no luck, now it's just working as it should be, without dhcpcd or dhclient being present...

The only thing I could imagine as a reason is this: There was a problem with the DNS server set by DHCP (the server was misconfigured / did not exist). This should not have caused the whole DHCP query to fail IMHO, but it's the only thing that really changed in the meantime...

Anyway, thanks to everyone looking at my question and thinking about it! :)